# Spring-Boot Error Page mapping & NestedServletException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that I am running as a standalone WAR file on Tomcat.

I have normal error page mappings in my error configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
class ErrorConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

  @Override public void customize( ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container ) {
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "/400" ) )
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "/403" ) )
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404" ) )
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, "/405" ) )   
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500" ) )
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED, "/501" ) )
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY, "/502" ) )
      container.addErrorPages( new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "/503" ) )
  }
```

This all works fine, however, I also have some exceptions that get thrown from other libraries that I want to map to specific error codes (equivalents of not found/not authorised that I want to map to 404/403s etc) - However, the exceptions thrown in my controllers seem to be wrapped in `NestedServletException` , which means when I add a custom `ErrorPage` with my exception, it is never mapped correctly.

Is there a way to get around this without explicitly catching the exceptions and re-throwing them as something else?  I have managed to get it working by extending the `ErrorPageFilter` and checking for this exception and checking the underlying cause, but would prefer not to have to do that.

Is that by design? Anyone encountered and worked out an elegant solution?  Two solutions I have come up with is custom `ErrorPageFilter` (which is not great as it makes it potentially harder to upgrade versions etc) or have a global `@ControllerAdvice` exception handler to catch these exceptions and then throw them back up again - any better options? Is this something that is going to be fixed/changed?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will throw a `NestedServletException` if there was an exception resolving your exception. I don't believe that's your issue here though. :)

As for mapping exceptions (third party, external, etc) to HTTP status codes, you can use a combination of `@ControllerAdvice`, `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseCode` without throwing the exception back up.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class CustomExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)  // 404
    @ExceptionHandler(SomeThirdPartyException.class)
    public void handleSomeThirdPartyException() {}
}
```